# Error when using R Blogdown blogdown:::serve_site()

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm using R blogdown `blogdown:::serve_site()`,and the result is below:

```
    Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\xsong\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." -f toml' execution failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning message:
In blogdown::new_site() : The directory '.' is not empty
> blogdown::new_site()
Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in F:\wwe.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   Choose a theme from https://themes.gohugo.io/, or
   create your own with the "hugo new theme <THEMENAME>" command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new <SECTIONNAME>\<FILENAME>.<FORMAT>".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

Visit https://gohugo.io/ for quickstart guide and full documentation.
trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/archive/master.zip'
downloaded 117 KB

processing 7 content files
Building sites 鈥?panic: Too many homes

goroutine 76 [running]:
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).createMissingPages(0xc00030f180, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites.go:627 +0x111f
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).assemble(0xc00030f180, 0xc000389c00, 0xc0005cdc70, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:245 +0x141
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2.2()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:98 +0x43
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0004d4ba0, 0x129dfd2, 0x8, 0xc0005cdd20)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2(0xc00049bdc0, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:100 +0x244
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func3()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:109 +0x36
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0004d4ba0, 0x129b050, 0x7, 0xc00049bec8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build(0xc00030f180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:111 +0x7c4
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).buildSites(...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:763
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).fullBuild.func3(0x8, 0x134c5d8)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:313 +0x80
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1(0xc0004d4b70, 0xc0002f0d30)
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:58 +0x5e
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:55 +0x6d
Building sites 鈥?panic: Too many homes

goroutine 85 [running]:
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).createMissingPages(0xc000435180, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites.go:627 +0x111f
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).assemble(0xc000435180, 0xc0003bce00, 0xc0005e1c70, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:245 +0x141
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2.2()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:98 +0x43
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0003c13e0, 0x129dfd2, 0x8, 0xc0005e1d20)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2(0xc000355dc0, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:100 +0x244
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func3()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:109 +0x36
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0003c13e0, 0x129b050, 0x7, 0xc000355ec8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build(0xc000435180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:111 +0x7c4
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).buildSites(...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:763
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).fullBuild.func3(0x8, 0x134c5d8)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:313 +0x80
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1(0xc0003c13b0, 0xc000215ae0)
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:58 +0x5e
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:55 +0x6d
系统找不到指定的路径。
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\xsong\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium' execution failed with error code 1
> blogdown:::serve_site()
Building sites 鈥?panic: Too many homes

goroutine 73 [running]:
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).createMissingPages(0xc0002e12d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites.go:627 +0x111f
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).assemble(0xc0002e12d0, 0xc000472000, 0xc000549c70, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:245 +0x141
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2.2()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:98 +0x43
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0001b2120, 0x129dfd2, 0x8, 0xc000549d20)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2(0xc0005afdc0, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:100 +0x244
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func3()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:109 +0x36
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc0001b2120, 0x129b050, 0x7, 0xc0005afec8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build(0xc0002e12d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:111 +0x7c4
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).buildSites(...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:763
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).fullBuild.func3(0x8, 0x134c5d8)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:313 +0x80
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1(0xc0001b20f0, 0xc0005800e0)
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:58 +0x5e
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:55 +0x6d
Building sites 鈥?panic: Too many homes

goroutine 31 [running]:
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).createMissingPages(0xc000097180, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites.go:627 +0x111f
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).assemble(0xc000097180, 0xc000298000, 0xc0005efc70, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:245 +0x141
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2.2()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:98 +0x43
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc00040c4e0, 0x129dfd2, 0x8, 0xc0005efd20)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func2(0xc0002b9dc0, 0x20)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:100 +0x244
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build.func3()
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:109 +0x36
runtime/trace.WithRegion(0x14f5060, 0xc00040c4e0, 0x129b050, 0x7, 0xc0002b9ec8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/annotation.go:137 +0xf0
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib.(*HugoSites).Build(0xc000097180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/hugolib/hugo_sites_build.go:111 +0x7c4
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).buildSites(...)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:763
github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands.(*commandeer).fullBuild.func3(0x8, 0x134c5d8)
    /go/src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commands/hugo.go:313 +0x80
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1(0xc00040c390, 0xc000112030)
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:58 +0x5e
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    /go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20180314180146-1d60e4601c6f/errgroup/errgroup.go:55 +0x6d
系统找不到指定的路径。
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\xsong\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" --themesDir themes -t hugo-lithium' execution failed with error code 1
```

It seems that there are some problems of hugo lithium theme. I also cannot successfully use `blogdown::new_site()` to bulid a new site. I have tried to reinstall blogdown and hugo, but it does not work.

Please help me.

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, [this conversation](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/255) on GitHub might have some useful info for you.